# crear trigger para sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Soy un poco nuevo en sql server, y tengo una tabla la cual se llama clientes. lo que quiero es crear un trigger que al borrar un registro de mi tabla clientes el trigger me inserte ese registro borrado en mi tabla historial.
No se como hacerlo ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los triggers (para DML) son procedimientos almacenados que tienen 2 características principales. Se ejecutan dentro de la misma transacción que los desencadena y tienen acceso a las tablas especiales `inserted` y `deleted`. Cuando ocurre un `INSERT` se utiliza la tabla inserted, cuando ocurre un `DELETE` se utiliza la tabla deleted y cuando ocurre un `UPDATE` se utilizan ambas tablas para obtener los valores anteriores y los nuevos. Estas tablas solo tienen las filas afectadas por la operación, por lo que es más sencillo controlarlas.
Aquí dejo un ejemplo de como hacer un trigger de auditoría para un `DELETE`.

```
CREATE TABLE EjemploClientes(
    idCliente   int,
    NombreCliente   varchar(100),
    FechaAlta       date);

CREATE TABLE EjemploClientesBorrados(
    idCliente   int,
    NombreCliente   varchar(100),
    FechaAlta       date,
    FechaBorrado    datetime,
    Usuario         sysname);

GO
CREATE TRIGGER TD_EjemploClientes ON EjemploClientes
FOR DELETE
AS
BEGIN TRY
    INSERT INTO EjemploClientesBorrados(
        idCliente       ,
        NombreCliente   ,
        FechaAlta       ,
        FechaBorrado    ,
        Usuario         )
    SELECT idCliente,
        NombreCliente,
        FechaAlta,
        GETDATE(),
        SUSER_SNAME()
    FROM deleted;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    THROW;
END CATCH;
GO

INSERT INTO EjemploClientes
VALUES( 1, 'Cliente 1', GETDATE()-3),
      ( 2, 'Cliente 2', GETDATE()-2),
      ( 3, 'Cliente 3', GETDATE()-1);

SELECT * FROM EjemploClientes;
SELECT * FROM EjemploClientesBorrados;

GO
DELETE EjemploClientes WHERE idCliente < 3;
GO

SELECT * FROM EjemploClientes;
SELECT * FROM EjemploClientesBorrados;

GO
DROP TABLE EjemploClientes, EjemploClientesBorrados;
```

Habría indicado ver [la documentación de Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), pero los ejemplos no son del todo buenos.